# Http Post for WebClient

Tags: asynchronous, vert.x, vertx-httpclient, vert.x-webclient

I am trying to test my Post endpoint using WebClient of Vertx and always get 500 as a status code. 
Can anyone please let me know what am I doing wrong here:-

```
final String jsonBody = "{\"url\": \"https://www.google.se\"}";
    WebClient.create(vertx)
            .post(8080, "::1", "/service")
            .sendJson(
                jsonBody,
                response ->
                    testContext.verify(
                        () -> {
                          System.out.println(response.result().statusCode());
                          assertEquals("OK", response.result());
                        }));
```

Comment: No logs in your service? You could also print the body of the response in case the server included a message.

Comment: The code itself is OK.

Status code 500 Internal server error might suggest that something wrong has happend in your service e.g. Unhandled exception has been thrown.

Answer (score 0):

500 is an internal server error.
It is not getting the required data in your case..I guess.
So try to send the payload using

- Convert string to jsonobject and send usig [sendJsonObject](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/client/HttpRequest.html#sendJsonObject-io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject-io.vertx.core.Handler-) method
- Convert buffer to jsonobject and send usig [sendBuffer](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/client/HttpRequest.html#sendBuffer-io.vertx.core.buffer.Buffer-io.vertx.core.Handler-) method

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. I show both the Vert.x client and the handler. The client creates a `JsonObject` from the string. The handler is in the server.

```
@Test
public void testPostURL(TestContext context) {
    Async async = context.async();
    final String body = "{\"url\": \"https://www.google.se\"}";
    WebClient.create(vertx)
            .post(8080, "localhost", "/service")
            .putHeader("content-type", "application/json")
            .sendJson( new JsonObject(body),
                     requestResponse -> {
                        context.assertEquals(requestResponse.result().statusCode(), 200);
                        async.complete();
                    });
}
```

The handler expects a JsonObject and returns the url (https://www.google.se)

```
    private void service(RoutingContext rc) {
    HttpServerResponse response = rc.response();
    JsonObject body = rc.getBodyAsJson();
    String site = body.getString("url");
    response.setStatusCode(200)
            .putHeader("content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
            .end(Json.encodePrettily(site));
}
```